# Adding SFTP to Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, ftp, sftp

I need SFTP functionality on my Windows 2012 VPS server.

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui), one of the prerequisites is that I'm running at least Windows Server 2019 or Windows 10 (build 1809).

My hosting company says they can migrate everything to Windows Server 2022, but there will be costs and my sites will obviously be down for a little while.

1. Does anyone know if a SFTP server can be installed on Windows Server 2012?
2. Does anyone have experience doing this? Any recommendations?
3. Would this be greatly simplified if I used plain ol' FTP? I don't think our data is particularly sensitive.

Comment: Considered Filezilla Server? It's not integrated, but it works for us and does not seem to need any particular Windows version.

Comment: @tsc_chazz: I can check that out, thanks. Is it very difficult to configure on Windows? I'm actually a developer and not so much an admin guy.

Comment: @tcs_chazz: Looks like the current version says *The 64bit versions of Windows 8.1 and 10 are supported.* So I don't know if Windows 2012 is.

Comment: @JonathanWood Server2012R2 is equal to win8.1. Stuff that works on 8.1 probably works on 2012R2. Anyway, consider upgrading, [win2012R2 is EOL in october next year.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-server-2012-r2)

Comment: @JonathanWood yes, Win 8.1 and Server 2012 R2 share a code base, and I've used it on that platform. But vidarlo is correct - it's time and past time to consider an update.

Comment: @vidarlo: Thanks for the info and the link. But that page seems indicates Extended Security Updates extends critical/important support until 2026.

Comment: Are you prepared to pay hundreds of dollars per year for ESU? ESU is not free upgrades. It's a paid service for those who ***can't*** move right now. To be blunt: you are *not* in that situation. Upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q:  SFTP server can be installed on Windows Server 2012?

A: Of *COURSE* you can! [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is an excellent choice.  So is [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server).  The latter also has a great NuGet package for programming SFTP with C#/ASP.NET.  You have many other options as well, both "paid" and "open source".

PS: Please do *NOT* use FTP.  SFTP is really the most prudent choice, even if you "don't think your data is particularly sensitive...."

Comment: Those are *clients*, not *servers*.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can install [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) at Windows 2012 [R2] server and it configures like on any other platform (e.g. Linux) and works as expected.

Comment: As stated in my OP, Microsoft specifically says Windows Server 2019 or later is a prerequisite for installing OpenSSH. I don't know

Comment: I belive Microsoft says about this prerequisites for OpenSSH server included in Windows server 2019 (and Windows 10) as 'Furure on demand'. You can install open ssh server on any previous version of Windows Server from  downloaded installation package anyway...